# Select min of one column and max another column of consecutive numbers when other columns are the same

Tags: sql

I need some help with the following. Let me explain with an example because I am not sure how to put it into words.
I have the following table:

| ID | ColumnA | ColumnB | Y/N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 322 | 0 | 3 | Y |
| 322 | 3 | 5 | Y |
| 322 | 5 | 6 | N |
| 322 | 6 | 8 | N |
| 322 | 8 | 12 | Y |
| 566 | 0 | 30 | Y |
| 566 | 30 | 31 | Y |
| 566 | 31 | 35 | N |

I would like to get the following output:

| ID | ColumnA | ColumnB | Y/N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 322 | 0 | 5 | Y |
| 322 | 5 | 8 | N |
| 322 | 8 | 12 | Y |
| 566 | 0 | 31 | Y |
| 566 | 31 | 35 | N |

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and one approach uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY A) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, YN ORDER BY A) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, MIN(A) AS A, MAX(B) AS B, YN
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID, YN, rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY ID, A;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

If we look closely at the `GROUP BY` clause above, we can see that we aggregating by `ID`, `YN`, and also a pseudo group defined as the difference in two row number sequences.  This `rn1 - rn2` sequence keeps track of to which particular island a group of records having the same `ID` and `YN` belongs.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the super detailed explanation. It makes a lot of sense!